# Market clearing price for a single good with two consumers with different utilities

Tags: utility, markets

Say I have a single indivisible good that is randomly allocated to one of two consumers.  The first consumer's utility for the good is \$5 and the second consumer's utility for it is $10.

If the good is allocated to the 2nd consumer, we have a Pareto equilibrium and no trades should occur.

But if the good is allocated to the first consumer, both consumers will benefit from trading the good at any price between \$5 and $10.

My question is whether there is any general theory with minimal assumptions that will give a single price at which the trade will occur?  Assume that either both consumers have perfect or no information about each other's utilities.

Comment: Please define "*general theory with minimal assumptions*".

Cooperative game theory provides several different answers to this question, but I would not call the assumptions minimal.

Comment: In the same vein as Giskard's comment, a non-cooperative game like take-it-or-leave-it game would give you one as well. We need more information.

Comment: Well "minimal" is obviously relative.  I meant the least amount of assumptions that will still allow for the determination of a single trade price.  I finally found the relevant search terms and this section of Wikipedia mostly answers my question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_auction#Mechanism_design